# how to get email id in some specific format from database

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to write a procedure that can that select email id from table column but i want in some specific format when email id is return then first 4 letter and last 4 letter will only show and remaining will display in ****** format.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `substr` and `lpad` function as following:

```
Select case when length(email_id) > 8 then substr(email_id, 1, 4) 
       || lpad(substr(email_id, -4), length(email_id) - 4, '*') 
      else email_id end as new_email_id
from your table
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This gives an incorrect answer for strings of 5, 6 or 7 characters [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0ea639b13ce009121778482b09cac475)

Comment: Good!! I have corrected it to check for minimum 8 characters.

Comment: i have 4 column in my database table 
LOG_TIME
LOGIN_NAME
USER_IDENTITY
CREATION_TIME

under LOGIN_NAME i have many user my first user ACCOUNT_ASSIGNED_TIME IS CREATION_TIME but when the 2nd user is come his ACCOUNT_ASSIGNED_TIME  is 1st user MAX(LOG_TIME).

this is actually my user_log table whatever the record edited against particular user then log is created.

so i want the users assigned time.


thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if the email has more than 8 characters and if it does take the first 4 characters and the last 4 characters and concatenate a sub-string of repeated stars in the middle to make up the remaining characters:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( email ) AS
SELECT 'a@bc'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ab@c.def'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc@d.efg'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc@defg.hij' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT email,
       CASE
       WHEN LENGTH( email ) <= 8
       THEN email
       ELSE SUBSTR( email, 1, 4 )
            || LPAD( '*', LENGTH( email ) - 8, '*' )
            || SUBSTR( email, -4 )
       END AS replaced_email
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> EMAIL        | REPLACED_EMAIL
> :----------- | :-------------
> a@bc         | a@bc          
> ab@c.def     | ab@c.def      
> abc@d.efg    | abc@*.efg     
> abc@defg.hij | abc@****.hij
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf9a12153b65e4bdf89c0d0447648ef7)*

Answer (score 0):

The following query will do what you want:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN LENGTH(EMAIL_ADDR) > 8 THEN
           SUBSTR(EMAIL_ADDR, 1, 4) || RPAD('*', LENGTH(EMAIL_ADDR)-8, '*') || SUBSTR(EMAIL_ADDR, -4)
         ELSE EMAIL_ADDR
       END AS ANONYMIZED_EMAIL_ADDR
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Examples:

```
EMAIL_ADDR                  ANONYMIZED_EMAIL_ADDR
billg@microsoft.com         bill***********.com
fred.rogers@npr.com         fred***********.com
santa.claus@northpole.org   sant*****************.org
x@y.z                       x@y.z
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=99dec91b53f71d0d94e6e58b6ee48e82)